# How can I convert ticks to a date format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am converting a ticks value to a date like this:

```
Convert(datetime, (MachineGroups.TimeAdded - 599266080000000000)/864000000000);
```

Using this i get:

```
9/27/2009 10:50:27 PM
```

But I want just the date in this format:

```
October 1, 2009
```

My sample ticks value is

```
633896886277130000
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Seems like a perfectly real question to me about how to format DateTime.ToString() output.

Comment: If he read my response to his question from yesterday, I already provided the code for this...

Comment: I edited the question pretty heavily to make it sound more legit.  The original was in need of improvement.

Comment: He did provide an attempt at code, so at least he showed effort.  Didn't know about this having been asked yesterday though.  Still, I'm getting to the point where I might not read questions from "unknown (google)."  They do tend to not invest much time in formulating the question well.

Answer (score 216):

A DateTime object can be constructed with a specific value of ticks.  Once you have determined the ticks value, you can do the following:

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(numberOfTicks);
String test = myDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Answer (score 66):

It's much simpler to do this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(633896886277130000);
```

Which gives

```
dt.ToString() ==> "9/27/2009 10:50:27 PM"
```

You can format this any way you want by using `dt.ToString(MyFormat)`.  Refer to [this reference](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) for format strings. `"MMMM dd, yyyy"` works for what you specified in the question.

Not sure where you get October 1.

Comment: october 1 is just a format sample..

I need the convert statement so i can use it in the SQL select statement

Answer (score 7):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long myTicks = 633896886277130000;
        DateTime dtime = new DateTime(myTicks);
        MessageBox.Show(dtime.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy"));
    }
```

Gives

```
September 27, 2009
```

Is that what you need?

I don't see how that format is necessarily easy to work with in SQL queries, though.

Answer (score 4):

Answers so far helped me come up with mine.  I'm wary of UTC vs local time; ticks should always be UTC IMO.

```
public class Time
{
    public static void Timestamps()
    {
        OutputTimestamp();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        OutputTimestamp();
    }

    private static void OutputTimestamp()
    {
        var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
        var localTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        var localTime = new DateTime(timestamp, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime();
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Timestamp = {0}.  Local ticks = {1}.  Local time = {2}.", timestamp, localTicks, localTime);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Timestamp = 636988286338754530.  Local ticks = 636988034338754530.  Local time = 2019-07-15 4:03:53 PM.
Timestamp = 636988286348878736.  Local ticks = 636988034348878736.  Local time = 2019-07-15 4:03:54 PM.
```

Comment: Upvoted for caring about UTC when storing date/times. Varying timezones can cause a lot of trouble when retrieving the time at a later stage if timezone might have changed.