# SQL date conversion year/datepart to datetime

Tags: sql, date-conversion

I am trying to convert from "tick" `date` format to a `datetime` format. 
Example:

> 0000113326 to 2013-11-22 00:00:00.000

I know how to go the opposite way:

```
SELECT '00001' + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(StartDate) AS varCHAR(4)), 2) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(Datepart(dy, StartDate) AS VARCHAR(3)), 3)
FROM table
```

I just need to reverse engineer it.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert ticks to a date format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489243/how-can-i-convert-ticks-to-a-date-format)

Comment: @abhi I think the definition of "ticks" is different between the two questions.

Comment: Yes, different terms. I am using Ticks because I am not sure what to call the date format of 0000113326.

Comment: What are your "ticks" a count of? without knowing that, we can't really help you.

Comment: @NicholasCarey,I assume, that the last three digits show the day in year and to digits before them the year in current century.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @tick varchar(20) = '0000113326'
SELECT dateadd(d, cast(right(@tick, 3) as int) - 1, '20' + substring(@tick, 6, 2) + '0101')
```