# Verify if a value is a tick in c#

Tags: c#, .net, date, time

I have a time tick (635655080937662522) I created with C# and stored in a database column.  How can I verify that this value is a tick and not something else? Does a tick have a certain format?

Comment: A tick count is just a number, so anything ranging from 0 to long.MaxValue is acceptable.

Comment: About the only thing you can do is convert it back to a DateTime and see if its within a reasonable range.

Comment: I suppose "invalid tick" would date to the year 2410, for example? If so, you can create a `DateTime` from the ticks and check if it's in a reasonable date range. You should, however, be asking yourself "why would it ever be an invalid number, and what can I do to prevent that?"

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489243/how-can-i-convert-ticks-to-a-date-format

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, a tick is just a number, but there are some important differences, depending on where the tick came from.

- Ticks from a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` are 100ns each, and range from `DateTime.MinValue.Ticks` to `DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks`, which is `0` to `3155378975999999999`.  Note that this is much smaller than `Int64.MaxValue`.
- Ticks from a `TimeSpan` are also 100ns each, but range from `TimeSpan.MinValue.Ticks` to `TimeSpan.MaxValue.Ticks`, which is the same as the range of `Int64`, which is `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`.
- Ticks from a `Stopwatch` (in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace) are of varying size, depending on the hardware capabilities of the system.  They are usually around 4ns on modern hardware.  You can adjust them to `TimeSpan` ticks by using `Stopwatch.Elapsed.Ticks` instead of `Stopwatch.ElaspedTicks`, or by taking the [`Stopwatch.Frequency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx) into account in your calculations.  The range is `0` to `Int64.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 2):

Tick is a number, there is really not much more validation you can do.

You can check if actual time is in particular range that makes sense for your case, but it is application specific.