# How to convert ticks from java to DateTime c# with time zone

Tags: java, c#, datetime

I Have this tick number `1448013624577` from a java site and im trying to convert to a c# `DateTime` doing this

```
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(1448013624577 / 1000d);
```

But the hour of this tick are 2 hours after the hour of the `DateTime`

My time zone is (GMT-3) but right now I'm in daylight save (GMT-2)

How can I convert this tick with my time zone?

Comment: You don't change GMT. The fact there's a daylight saving time applied doesn't mean your time zone changes. Use the same timezone to declare the base day(1970-01-01 00:00:00) first and then add the proper seconds, regardless of the programming language.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for the enlightenment about the daylight. but i think this information in my question are relevant because the 2 hours of difference between expected and actual

Comment: I mean that if you use the same time zone for both dates then you will get the same dste but probably they'll look different due to presentation issues (not bugs). As an example, here in Peru GMT -5 we're at 3:26 but in Chicago GMT CST they're at 2:26 but it's the dame date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using DateTimeOffset

```
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(1448013624577 / 1000d);

var dof = new DateTimeOffset(dt, new TimeSpan(0));

var dtGmt = dof.ToLocalTime().DateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `DateTime myDate = new DateTime(numberOfTicks);`?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489276/2874896).

Comment: That is the number of ticks since January 1st of the year 1.  Not 1970.

Comment: and the site isnt in my time zone

Comment: What about using ConvertTime once the date is created? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx