# How to convert ticker value to datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime, ticker

I have the following values:

> 1465509600000
>
> 1402437600000

I tried the following:

attempt 1:

```
    public long? CommitmentStartDate { get; set; }

    public long? CommitmentEndDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CommitmentStartDateDate => new DateTime( (CommitmentStartDate != null ? (long)CommitmentStartDate: Convert.ToInt64(DateTime.MinValue)) );

    public DateTime? CommitmentEndDateDate => new DateTime(CommitmentEndDate != null ? (long)CommitmentEndDate: Convert.ToInt64(DateTime.MinValue));
```

This gives me the date in the worng format, i get this:

> 0001-01-02 16:42:30
>
> 0001-01-02 14:57:23

attempt 2:

```
    static readonly DateTime _unixEpoch =
         new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public static DateTime DateFromTimestamp(long timestamp)
    {
        return _unixEpoch.AddSeconds(timestamp);
    }

    public long? CommitmentStartDate { get; set; }

    public long? CommitmentEndDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CommitmentStartDateDate =>  DateFromTimestamp(CommitmentStartDate != null ? (long)CommitmentStartDate: Convert.ToInt64(DateTime.MinValue));

    public DateTime? CommitmentEndDateDate => DateFromTimestamp(CommitmentEndDate != null ? (long)CommitmentEndDate: Convert.ToInt64(DateTime.MinValue));
```

this gave me an argumentOutOfRange exception.

How do I do this?

EDIT:

Expected values:

> 2014-06-11
>
> 2016-06-10

EDIT 2:

Ticks that come from date

> 1402437600000 ---- > 2014-06-11
>
> 1465509600000 ---- > 2016-06-10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert ticks to a date format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489243/how-can-i-convert-ticks-to-a-date-format)

Comment: Way too much fluff. Please just post 1 or more samples with their expected date values.

Comment: @François Wahl Thats the thread that i used when trying to convert this, would be nice if you would read through the entire question with code before voting to close

Comment: `DateTime`s don't have a specific format associated with them.

Comment: could you specify what the "ticks" represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2 samples are 2 years apart, taking the difference from those ticks and dividing by 2, 365, 24 and 3600 leaves 1000 so they are milliseconds.

A quick check reveals that they are indeed based on 1-1-1970 so

```
//return _unixEpoch.AddSeconds(timestamp);
return _unixEpoch.AddMilliSeconds(timestamp);
```

Comment: Anyway, with the sample "ticks" OP shows, the results would be `2016-06-09 22:00:00` and `2014-06-10 22:00:00`

Comment: Yes, there appears to be a Timezone offset involved, I got a base of 1-1-70, 02:00. Easy to compensate but it is always so much better to have specs for your incoming data.

Answer (score 1):

In this part you are adding seconds:

```
public static DateTime DateFromTimestamp(long timestamp)
{
    return _unixEpoch.AddSeconds(timestamp);
}
```

If you want to pass ticks, you need to add ticks:

```
public static DateTime DateFromTimestamp(long timestamp)
{
    return _unixEpoch.AddTicks(timestamp);
}
```

But you have to be sure that **your ticks mean the same as .NET ticks**. One .NET tick is **100 nanoseconds**. If your tick is a different unit, you have to convert it to .NET ticks first.

Answer (score 1):

I used this extension

```
public static DateTime FromUnixTicks(this double ms)
{
    DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    return d1.AddMilliseconds(ms).ToLocalTime();
}
```

and sample:

```
1465509600000.0.FromUnixTicks()
```

and convert back

```
public static double ToUnixTicks(this DateTime dt)
{
    DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    DateTime d2 = dt.ToUniversalTime();
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);
    return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

I needed `double` here, but you can use `long`, I guess.