# Passing dates between c# and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC app that returns a view model, which when converted to JSON using system.web.mvc.jsonresult looks as follows:

[image]

On the client I'm using KnockoutJS. I use MomentJS to format the value for the VoucherDate so that it can be displayed for humans:

```
 var recsArray = [];
                $.each(data.Vouchers, function (key, value) {
                    recsArray.push(
                        new edited(
                            interchangeId,
                            value.SupplierIsValid,
                            value.VoucherNo,
                            value.LegacySupplierId,
                            value.Transactions,
                            moment(value.OriginalVoucher.VoucherDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm'),
                            value.OriginalVoucher
                            )
                    );
```

As you can see from the previous code snippet, in addition to pushing the data into an observable array for display in a KOGrid, I also push the entire "OriginalVoucher". This enables the user to edit the value for "LegacySupplierId" and click "Resubmit" which posts back the entire view model as seen below:

```
self.resubmit = function () {
        var data = {
            Vouchers: ko.toJS(this.recs),
            BatchId: self.batchId(),
            InterchangeId: interchangeId,
            IsReadWrite: self.isReadWrite,
            Interface: self.interface,
            ReportClient: self.reportClient
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: BASE_URL + 'EditBatch/ResubmitRejectedVouchersAsNewBatch',
            data:  ko.toJSON(data),
```

I've checked using Fiddler and confirmed that the VoucherDate fields contain values such as /Date(14543712000000)/. My problem is, when reading in the C# controller, all of the dates are presented as 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.

[image]

I've read that javascript has a date.toISOString() function to convert to a format that C# will be happy with. Is there a better way that trying to find each date field in the javascript view model and executing a conversion against each before posting back to the C# controller

I think I have previously solved this problem using automapper by following instructions here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters)

In my source code I can see that I created the following class but I don't know how / if this gets used:

```
public class JsonDateTimeTypeConvertor : ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        string jsonDate = context.SourceValue.ToString();

        string offsetAsString = Regex.Match(jsonDate, @"\d+").Value;
        double offset = System.Convert.ToDouble(offsetAsString);

        DateTime ret = DataUtils.ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(offset);

        return ret;
    }

}
```

I think it was being used but I've inadvertently disabled it. This probably happened when I changed the type for the ViewModel received by the controller. The previous version of the application worked, so I guess the datetime was being converted correctly - probably by this automapper extension. I have pulled the old version of the code from TFS but can't figure out how it's doing the magic - I wish I'd made better notes at the time! All I have is:

> I needed to create a custom type convertor to deal with JSON dates being passed to the EditBatch controller in the format of number of milliseconds since 1900.
>
> I followed the wiki documentation from here:
>
> https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters

Comment: VoucherDate looks like it's in ticks - C# has a DateTime constructor that will take ticks directly, if you're able to pass that value in. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489243/how-can-i-convert-ticks-to-a-date-format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work-around this by changing the data type on the "VoucherDate" field in the C# model from DateTime to String. I don't currently understand why this works. I also think there must be a better way!?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use a regex pattern like this. The following code shows ToJavaScriptDate() function that does this for you:

```
function ToJavaScriptDate(value) 
{
var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
var results = pattern.exec(value);
var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
}
```

The ToJavaScriptDate() function accepts a value in /Date(ticks)/ format and returns a date string in MM/dd/yyyy format. Inside, the ToJavaScriptDate() function uses a regular expression that represents a pattern /Date(([^)]+))/.

The exec() method accepts the source date value and tests for a match in the value. The return value of exec() is an array. In this case the second element of the results array (results[1]) holds the ticks part of the source date. For example, if the source value is /Date(836418600000)/ then results[1] will be 836418600000. Based on this ticks value a JavaScript Date object is formed. The Date object has a constructor that accepts the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970. Thus dt holds a valid JavaScript Date object. The ToJavaScriptDate() function then formats the date as MM/dd/yyyy and returns to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not a fan of the way the default JavaScriptConverter handles dates.  I use the following class. (The CustomString class is kind of a dirty hack to get around the fact that the Serialize command is expected to return an IDictionary.  See blog post here: http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2011/12/custom-datetime-json-serialization/)

```
public class DateTimeJsonSerializer : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            return null;

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().ConvertToType(dictionary, type);
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!(obj is DateTime)) return null;

        return new CustomString(((DateTime) obj).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"));
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Type>(new List<Type> { typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTime?) }); }
    }
}

public class CustomString : Uri, IDictionary<string, object>
{
    public CustomString(string str) : base(str, UriKind.Relative)
    {}

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, object>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; private set; }
    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Add(string key, object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(string key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public ICollection<string> Keys { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<object> Values { get; private set; }
}
```

To use this in asp.net, I have the following section in my web.config (make sure to replace "AssemblyNameGoesHere" with the assembly that contains the converter class:

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644">
          <converters>
            <add name="DateTimeConverter" type="DateTimeJsonSerializer,AssemblyNameGoesHere" />
          </converters>
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```