# ListView representation - ticks to DateTime

Tags: listview, datetime, xamarin.forms

Within an ObservableCollection, Ticks are stored.
The collection content is bound to a list view.

I do not wanna present ticks but DateTime.

From and To are long ticks.
Note is a string.

```
<ListView x:Name="TimeLogView">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextCell Text="{Binding From}" Grid.Column="0" />
                                <TextCell Text="{Binding To}"   Grid.Column="1" />
                                <TextCell Text="{Binding Note}" Grid.Column="2" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                     </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Where/how must be the conversion (e.g.

> new DateTime(ticks)

) done from ticks to DateTime? Exists there a XAML format option? or must it be done in a C# file?

Comment: You can either do this directly while adding value in your ObservableCollection by converting the value of Note to your custom DateTime format. Or, you can implement a converter, that inherits from IValueConverter, in the XAML itself.

Comment: Note must not be changed. As mentioned, From and To must be changed - ticks. It is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where: 
In your case I would do the conversion in the `ViewModel`, since it looks like a very specific one-time conversion that you won't reuse globally in your app. Otherwise I would suggest to use a `IValueController`.

How: 
Add additional properties to you `ViewModel` that will expose the converted values.
Regarding the conversation itself, seems like this question have been asked multiple times on SO. Here is one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489243/how-can-i-convert-ticks-to-a-date-format).