# PHP: How to covert 18 digit time from a window server to local time

Tags: php, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I queried an API and I got this response

`$response = [635355360000000000.0, 6.400000, 6.510000, 6.400000, 6.470000, 1586684.00];`

The first element of the array is suppose to be date and when I looked around on how to convert it the closest code that got me an answer is this:

```
$dateLargeInt= $response[0];
$secsAfterADEpoch = $dateLargeInt / (10000000);

$ADToUnixConvertor=((1970-1601) * 365.242190) * 86400; 
// unix epoch - AD epoch * number of tropical days * seconds in a day 
$unixTsLastLogon=intval($secsAfterADEpoch-$ADToUnixConvertor); 

// unix Timestamp version of AD timestamp
$lastlogon=date("d-m-Y", $unixTsLastLogon); // formatted date

echo $lastlogon;
```

This was the result I got 12-05-3614

I also tried this:

```
$dateLargeInt= $response[0];
echo date('Y-d-m',$response[0]);
```

This was the result  20133611831-11-12

Comment: Did you check the API documentation?

Comment: @Opsse I checked the API and it clearly stated that the value in the array is time, it's a stock exchange API and that is a trade report of a company for that date.

Comment: @Opsse Thanks so much I just read the documentation. It says the date is in **ticks** what does that mean

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489243/how-can-i-convert-ticks-to-a-date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the documentation specify that date is in ticks you can read [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time).

[This article](https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/749/converting-datetime-ticks-to-a-unix-timestamp-and-back-in-php) could also help you to understand.

Then try this :

```
$seconds = ($response[0] - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $seconds);
```

Comment: got this `1990-02-18 15:36:00` which is contrary to what I got on [http://tickstodatetime.com/ ] **2014-05-13​T00:00:00.000Z**

Comment: My bad, I forgot to replace the `1000000000` by `10000000`.
Now : `(635355360000000000−621355968000000000)÷10000000 = 1399939200` which is the timestamp of *2014-05-13*

Comment: didn't know I was suppose to click the check button. Thanks though done that now.