# Converting DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x"); back to human readable timestamp

Tags: c#, google-sheets

I have a script that creates data and stores the with a name that contains the output of `DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");` I now need to convert this value back to a human readable time in order to figure out when the data was generated for a report but I cant find any tools or equations to do this anywhere. All help appreciated.

some values i'm trying to convert:

```
8d84e63114d60d2
8d84e6645daa831
8d84e67c9ba1367
8d84e6993166d49
```

Comment: `new DateTime(long.Parse("8d84e6993166d49", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))`.

Comment: `X` is hexadecimal. So you have two steps to your problem - convert hex back to the same type that `Ticks` is. Then call the appropriate constructor - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489270/34092 .

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert a small conversion script seems to be exactly what I needed