# System.FormatException: String '638143033743100000' was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime-format

Error:

```
System.FormatException: String '638143033743100000' was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

Current code already has provision to allow two different date format:

```
items = (await itemService.GetItems())
       .GroupBy(x => x.ItemKey)
       .Select(x => new DisplayItem
       {
           item = x.item,            
           country = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.item == "Country")?.Value,             
           date = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.item == "Date")?.Value != null
           ? DateTime.ParseExact(x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.item == "Date")?.Value, 
           new string[] {
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF",
            "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"}, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal)
           : (DateTime?)null
       }).Where(s => s.country!= null).OrderByDescending(s => s.date).ToList();
```

We have added a new date format. Using time in ticks now. May I know the format for ticks. Thank you.

Comment: If ticks mean the same definition as the one from .net then parse is to a long and call a DateTime constructor with it.

Comment: @Tar270 what is the format of the time ? Is it a Timestamp in `seconds` or Timestamp in `milliseconds` ?

Comment: Timestamp in milliseconds

Comment: Ticks in Net is 1Tick == 100Nanoseconds and by that definition your shown string equals last Thursday. So sounds feasible to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert ticks to a date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489243/how-can-i-convert-ticks-to-a-date-format)

Comment: @MartinSmith - Jason Berkan answer looks promising. But I have trouble incorporating in my query, which already allows two different date formats. Would appreciate if any help can be extended.

Comment: DateTime date = new DateTime();
            date = date.AddTicks(638143033743100000);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new method and use that instead of ParseExact directly and call that instead. Should make your code even more readable. Your handling of null cases in the midth of the linq statement is a maintenance mess.

```
.Select(x => new DisplayItem
   {
       item = x.item,            
       country = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.item == "Country")?.Value,             
       date = MyLovelyDateTimeParse(x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.item == 
       "Date")?.Value),
       ...... etc.
   })



public DateTime? MyLovelyDateTimeParse(string dateString)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateString))
        return null;
    else if (long.TryParse(dateString, out long value))
        return new DateTime(value);
    else
        return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,
            new string[] {
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF",
            "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"}, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);          
}
```

Comment: The parameter `dateString` should be a nullable string like so `string? dateString` and you should check against whitespaces too with `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: @Ralf, thanks a lot. looks promising. Says cannot convert from 'projectName.Shared.itemDetails' to 'string' when I add "date = MyLovelyDateTimeParse(x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.item == 
       "Date"))"

Comment: Added a sample of itemDetails class for your reference

Comment: Then call the fitting property on that itemDetails class Presumably Value. Update the code but that part is more or less guessing by me. I don't know to much about the actual structure you have.

Comment: That works perfect! You are rite. Item, country, date are all keys. Need to get the Value. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** Didn't see it was in ticks and not in UnixTime

To convert from `string` ticks to `DateTime`, parse it as a long and use the following

```
long ticks = 638143033743100000L;
DateTime dt = new(ticks);
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9krdFn)

And here is how you can use it in your code

```
items = (await itemService.GetItems())
   .GroupBy(x => x.ItemKey)
   .Select(x => new DisplayItem
   {
       item = x.item,            
       country = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.item == "Country")?.Value,             
       date = (x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.item == "Date") != null) && long.TryParse(x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.item == "Date").Value, out long l) && l > 0
       ? new DateTime(l) : (DateTime?)null
   }).Where(s => s.country!= null).OrderByDescending(s => s.date).ToList();
```

You can then set the formatting on your property `date` later down the line.

---

***Original answer:***

Here is how to convert a Timestamp to a DateTime

First, convert your string to a long

If it is in seconds

```
DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(long).UtcDateTime
```

If it is in milliseconds

```
DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(l).UtcDateTime;
```

It if better to make an extension method

```
public static class NumericExtensions
{
    public static DateTime ConvertFromTimestampSecondsToDateTime(this long l) => DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(l).UtcDateTime;
    public static DateTime ConvertFromTimestampMillisecondsToDateTime(this long l) => DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(l).UtcDateTime;
}
```

Then use them like so

```
long timestamp = 638143033743100000l;
DateTime dt = timestamp.ConvertFromTimestampMillisecondsToDateTime();
```

Comment: This code will throw an exception, have you tried it so far?

Comment: @shingo please elaborate. I have been using it without problems so far.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/r6tFbS

Comment: @Codingwiz thank you for the answer. I have trouble incorporating in my query, which already allows two different date formats. Would appreciate if any help can be extended.

Comment: @Tar270 you are trying to parse multiple `DateTime` formats and that is just asking for bugs. Refactor your code and stick to only one format at a time; either get date from `ticks` or get date from `ISO-8601`.

Comment: Edited back. You should accept the answer from @Ralf.