# Forcing a particular xml object serialization format

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using the C# serialization on one of my objects:

```
   StringWriter outStream = new StringWriter();
   XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
   XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
   s.Serialize(outStream, obj, ns);
   string xml = outStream.ToString();
```

The object is:

```
public class Points
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
    public string Type;
    public double Number;
}
```

My `Points` class is being used by another program expecting it in the form:

```
 <Points Type="Credit">123</Points>
```

I was trying to work if I can use any attributes to force this format?

Thanks

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307433/how-to-serialize-to-datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText]` attribute on the Number field, like you do with the `XmlAttribute` on the type:

```
public class Points
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
    public string Type;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText]
    public double Number;
}
```