# How do I get .Net XML deserialization to preserve DateTimeKind?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, xml-deserialization

I have an XML string with the following date: 2001-01-01T03:40:00Z

Note how it ends with Z, to indicate UTC.

I deserialize like so:

```
using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
        obj = (MyObject)sr.ReadObject(xmlReader);
```

But when I go to the corresponding DateTime fields in the resulting object, the Kind field is set to "Unspecified" rather than "Utc" which is what it should be. How do I work around this bug?

Answer (score 2):

The `Kind` field doesn't have a setter so the XmlSerializer won't be able to set it.

Many recommend always serializing the time as UTC and then calling ToLocalTime if you need it.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65164/best-practices-for-datetime-serialization-in-net-framework-3-5-sql-server-2008).

Comment: This is how we do it, and it works pretty well. The data itself always remains generic, and any views can reflect whatever time zone the system is set to.