# DateTime parameter is adjusted according to timezone

Tags: wcf, azure

I have a WCF Web-Service with a parameter of type DateTime. This Web-Service runs on Windows Azure. Our client is written in Java and run on a different time zone. When it calls this web-serve and passed a date-time (E.g. 2011-03-27 12:00+0100), the .NET Framework will automatically convert this date-time into the time zone of Windows Azure servers.

Is it possible to skip this conversion and get the exact time sent by the client?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behaviour: in general it's best to work with co-ordinated universal time when working with distributed services. In your case Azure / WCF should report the time as 13:00, as the Azure clocks are set to UT.

Assuming that your Java client encodes dates in the proper way, then

[Best practices for DateTime serialization in .NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65164/best-practices-for-datetime-serialization-in-net-framework-3-5-sql-server-2008)

gives some hints on how to extract out the local date and time and the timezone information entered by the user. (Scroll to the bottom answer.)